# Understanding a pure method @Contract

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I recently switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ and was quickly introduced to `@Contract` annotations and I instantly loved the concept behind these annotations (*"find problems in methods which call methods that you have annotated"*). My first thought was to use them to define getter and utility methods and the `pure` annotation parameter seems to fit that bill:

> The pure attribute is intended for methods that do not change the state of their objects, but just return a new value. If its return value is not used, removing its invocation will not affect program state or change the semantics, unless the method call throws an exception (exception is not considered to be a side effect).

However I am confused as what the above really means.

- Do mentioned objects refer to objects passed via method parameters or class fields? Further more, what would qualify as a *change*, changing object reference, content or probably both?
- Does invoking methods that change the state of these objects within the pure method violate the contract? Like builder methods that invokes constructors.
- When is it **objectively** considered best practice to mark methods as being pure? I know this might seem like a subjective question but there must be established community guidelines *(that can be referenced)* on when to do this.

Comment: Sounds like a pure method is [_side effect_](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect) free.

Comment: @Slaw I was not familiar with that term but it seems to have been mentioned in the `@Contract` documentation: *"A method should not be marked as pure if it does not produce a side effect by itself"*. So it would seem that any change to any object would be considered as a side effect.

Comment: @Matthew Yes. Pure basically means that the method is just a mathematical function. It takes some input values and it computes an output value. It does not modify the input values, nor the instance on which it is called and does not do any I/O (so no opening files, writing to logs etc).

Answer (score 3):

An example may be clarifying. Consider the following code:

```
class X {
  public void main(String[] ss) {
    ss[0].toUpperCase(java.util.Locale.ENGLISH);
  }
}
```

The `String.toUpperCase()` call does not change the object `ss[0]` it is called on, and also does not change the argument `java.util.Locale.ENGLISH` provided. It returns a new object, but that object is not used in the code. The call does not change the state of any objects in use in the program. Thus removing the call does not change the behaviour of the program. (Strictly speaking it will run very slightly faster, but this is not considered a relevant change in semantics.)

Note that when the `main` method is called with an empty array, it will throw an exception. When the call is removed this will not happen. But exceptions are not considered side-effects for the purpose of the `@Contract` annotation. Exceptions could be considered a type of return value.

Thus the `String.toUpperCase()` method can be annotated as pure. Pure methods are handled specially in many places in IntelliJ IDEA. For example if an unused variable is initialized by a pure method, the quick fix "knows" the initializer can be safely removed when removing the variable.

Getters are usually pure, `void` methods are usually not. But there are exceptions, for example `junit.framework.Assert.fail()` is `void` but `pure` as it has no side effects. As far as I'm aware there are no official guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

> Do mentioned objects refer to objects passed via method parameters or class fields?

Both, passed objects and fields of the instance the method is called on.

> Further more, what would qualify as a change, changing object reference, content or probably both?

Both. Any change qualifies.

> Does invoking methods that change the state of these objects within the pure method violate the contract?

Yes. Impurity is contagious: calling a non pure method from another method makes the latter non pure as well.

The crucial part is this:

> If its return value is not used, removing its invocation will not affect program state or change the semantics, unless the method call throws an exception (exception is not considered to be a side effect).

Leaving exceptions aside, another way of looking at this is: a method is pure whenever inlining that method does not change the semantics of your program.

Comment: Have you come across any community guidelines on when to mark methods as pure with @Contract annotation?